# IronPython IDE for Ubuntu and Linux

Tags: linux, ide, ironpython, monodevelop, pydev

I've been searching for an IDE with code completion (intellisence) for IronPython on Linux systems (typically Ubuntu).

I've found references to MonoDevelop and Eclipse (PyDev) supporting IronPython, but I can't get any of them to work.

Is this because MonoDevelop and PyDev only support IronPython code completion on Windows? Are there any installation guides that I could follow to make these IDEs work on Ubuntu / Linux.

Many thanks for your help,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Try [JetBrains PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Eclipse, but there isn't currently an IronPython addin for MonoDevelop. If anyone's interested in developing one, please contact the MonoDevelop mailing list for advice on getting started.

Answer (score 1):

[SharpDevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpDevelop) supports partial code completion for IronPython.  The IDE only runs on Windows but the IronPython code you develop should run on Mono provided that the libraries that you reference are supported on Mono.